# MongoDB BsonDocument size limit

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm experimenting with MongoDB for a pet project.  The domain model doesn't necessarily suit relational more than no-sql (as far as I'm aware), so it seemed like a good candidate to learn with.

The JSON representation of my model would look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": someId,
  "prop1": "foo",
  "prop2": "bar",
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "asdf",
      "uri": "http://foo.com/bar"
    },
    {
      "name": "asdf",
      "uri": "http://foo.com/bar2",
      "x": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "asdf",
      "uri": "http://foo.com/bar3"
    }
    ... /* there's going to be lots of these */
  ]
}
```

I understand that there's a hard limit on BSON document size of 16MB, and I could theoretically be recording hundreds of thousands of the 'entry' objects per document, which won't fit.

My initial thought was then to have 1 document per 'entry', stored in a different collection, with a reference back to the parent document.  eg:

**Parent collection**

```
{
  "_id": "parent1",
  "prop1": "foo",
  "prop2": "bar"
}
```

**Child collection**

```
{
  "_id": child1,
  "parentId": "parent1"
  "name": "asdf",
  "uri": "http://foo.com/bar1"
},
{
  "_id": child2,
  "parentId": "parent1"
  "name": "asdf",
  "uri": "http://foo.com/bar2",
  "x": 5
}
```

Trouble is, that seems very *relational* in style.

1. Am I fighting mongo's intended design?
2. Should I just stick with a relational db?

Comment: The schema design series on the mongodb blog might be a good read for you: [**part 1**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [**part 2**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) and [**part 3**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chridam, [this schema design guide](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) addressed my concerns.

Looks like you can still incorporate traditional relational concepts when dealing with MongoDb designs.

Comment: NoSQL doesn't mean there are no relations. Actually, your solution was pretty perfect. You might want to add proper indices though.

Comment: Yeah, my indices are actually GUIDs, I just couldn't be bothered putting real guids in the example :)

Comment: Which is not what I meant. Pretty sure you'll need an index over "parenthId" to find the childs efficiently.